# How can I access a class declared inside another class?

Tags: c++, class

I have declared a class responsible for hashing the main class inside it:

```
class MainClass
{
public:
    std::string s;

    struct Hash
    { std::size_t operator () (const MainClass&); };
}
```

But now I am struggling to access the Hash class. I tried in many ways, this being one of them:

```
MainClass mc;
mc.s = "a string";
std::cout << mc::Hash(mc); /// this doesn't work for a few reasons, the main one being that there is no instance of the Hash class
```

I tried declaring the function inside `Hash` as static, but that didn't do much either.

I tried creating an instance of `Hash` by doing `{ std::size_t operator () (const MainClass&); } instanceOfHash;` and tried accessing it like this: `std::cout << mc.instanceOfHash(mc);`, but it says *undefined reference to main::MainClass::Hash::operator() (MainClass const&)*.

Also, this is the definition of the overloaded operator if it helps:

```
std::size_t MainClass::Hash::operator () (const MainClass& mc)
{ return std::hash<std::string> () (mc.s); }
```

Comment: `MainClass::Hash{}(mc)` is what you need if that's really what you want to do, doesn't seem much point in having a class though, a static function would be simpler. The undefined reference is because you haven't provided a definition of the operator

Comment: Well, I have the definition that I put at the end of the question, and it should be right unless I messed something up I think...   Also, yeah, a static function would be easier, but I am asking in the general case, here I tried to simplify

Comment: It's difficult to know why you get an undefined reference without a [mre]

Comment: The definition looks okay, so you probably are not linking the file correctly (i.e. the issue is in how do you build the code, not in the code itself).

Comment: I assume you don't want a static function for a particular reason, so if you make a variable of your Hash struct then you can reference it like any other member of the class: https://onlinegdb.com/SydbDlctD  If you could use a static function then it might be simpler: https://onlinegdb.com/S1vQueqKP

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yeah, looking at this the next day, I think the way I linked them was the reason for the undefined reference

Answer (score 0):

The struct Hash can be defined inside the MainClass, and be treated as a member of the MainClass. The struct Hash can be reached by declaring a variable of type MainClass::Hash, and access its member functions via the variable.

```
//
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
//
class MainClass
{
   public:
   std::string s;
//
   struct Hash
     { std::size_t operator() (const MainClass& mc);
     };
};
std::size_t MainClass::Hash::operator() (const MainClass& m)
  {  return std::hash<std::string> () (m.s);
  }   
//
int main()
 {
    MainClass mc;
    MainClass::Hash h;
    std::cout << h(mc) << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(h).name() << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: My conclusion is that you cannot access the member function of Hash without given a object of Hash. You may assigne the object inside the class MainClass or in the Main(). If the object (h) is defined inside MainClass, then this object will be a member of the MainClass variable (mc), mc.h(mc); else if object h is defined in main(), mc and h has no direct relations. h(mc)  can actives the Hash member function operator().